# how to reduce vertical spacing in UICollection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using `UICollectionView` below is my code, How can i remove vertical spacing ?
I tried setting in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but didnot works.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cv: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cv.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        let xx : CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 8)
        let yy : CGFloat = 6.0
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: xx, height: yy)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        cv!.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 70
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        if (indexPath.row/2 == 0) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(12)
        }
        else if (indexPath.row/4 == 0) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        }
        else{
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protcol and `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` or `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` functions like below code:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10 // or any value
    }
    
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10 // or any value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spacing in your case is caused by the sizing -width, mainly- of each item.

So you have this code to calculate your single item width:

```
let xx : CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 8)
```

But since you have section insets, your calculation must change or you have to remove the insets, so either:

```
let xx : CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10 / 8)
// 10 = 5 left + 5 right is taken for section insets
```

Or, remove your section insets:

```
// layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
```

If you want to give leading/ trailing margin, use collection constraints instead, i.e. constraint the `collectionView` to the `leadingAnchor`/ `trailingAnchor` of it's superview with constant (say 5), then you don't have to do the calculation, since you can use the `sizeForItem` delegate method and return the calculation this way:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width / 8, height: 5.0)
 }
```